# html textarea with constant static uneditable readonly text at end

Tags: javascript, html, css

Having "fake" text inputs with various spans/divs inside the *perceived* text input is all the rage these days.  Look at Stackoverflow.  To Tag this question here, I am going to type h-t-m-l-<space> and it will turn that into a token/filter/tag.  This is pretty easy to do, put outer div with a border to look like a text input, hide borders for real text input and send click/focus events from the div to the text input.  Boom, you're done.  [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/RGHwf/)

I have a need to have the static text go after the input *and* I need this to be multiple lines.  I'm pretty sure I could get the text input example above to have the static text after the input with minor massaging. But going multiline seems  to be *really* hard.  If you go multiline, you have to use textareas (is this always true?).  Here's an image of what I want:

[image]

The whole area looks like a textarea to the user.  (The background color is just to help explain the question).  Imagine no green text initially, the red text is there though.  The user clicks anywhere inside the black border and his cursor goes to the upper right, like a normal empty textarea.  Then he types, and the red text just keeps moving along.  If the user clicks on, say, 'appending', his cursor goes right after the last green period, not in the word 'appending'.  The cursor can only ever be in the green section.

If you extend the solution for the single line text input to this, you would say that green would be a text area, the red would be a div, and the black border would be a container div.  But all divs have to be retangular (i think).  [This](http://jsfiddle.net/3aggN/) is my naive attempt with a similar solution as above.  But there are numerous problems with this.  How can the first line of the red start in the middle, and then the second line be flush on the left?  Here's what's on the jsfiddle:

```
div{
    width:200px;
    border:1px solid #000;
}
textarea{
    border:none;
    font-size:12px;
}
label{
    cursor:text;
    font-size:12px;
}

<div>
<textarea id="textarea">this is what the user entered</textarea>
<br>
<label for="textarea">This is my constant text</label>
</div>
```

I'm going to have the red populated dynamically with javascript, but for the purpose of this question, I think it's save to consider just static, constant html.

Is this solvable?

Comment: I'm sorry, but have you tried anything?  Otherwise it just seems you're asking for a complete solution without any attempts made c.c

Comment: perhaps you could try storing the red text as a variable, and replace/remove then append it to the end of the currently typed text on keyup and mouseclick. That way the red text is always added to the end.

Comment: of course, see the links to jsfiddle, but I just moved the code here for your perusal

Comment: @lukeocom I thought about that, but I would have to prohibit access to the red.  If he added a character in the red, it would not recognize that phrase exactly and append another red variable at the end. i could see this getting out of control very easily. blocking access to the red would be key here, i don't see a way to do that.

Comment: The only thing I can think of off hand is to make the element unselectable. I havent tested this so its just a thought and may not be of use, but... Something along the lines of <input onselectstart="return false;"  unselectable="on" style="cursor:default;   -moz-user-select: -moz-none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
    ">

Answer (score 0):

**1)** Create the *textarea*

**2)** Store your *static text* inside a variable.

**3)** Populate your *textarea* with the *static text* variable

**4)** When the user starts writing in the *textarea*(**ie:** onkeydown event, mouse event..), erase your static content. Store dynamic content in a new variable and keep updating it as user keeps typing. Meanwhile in the *textarea*, append static text after dynamic content only after user stops typing(**ie:** onkeyup event). Keep repeating this process.

**Calculations:**

> Dynamic Text = Length of *textarea*'s total text - Length of *static text*

Comment: Thank you for your thoughts.  Does this mean that the static text would "flash" or not be visible at some points?  Based on your description, keydown would remove it and keyup would put it back? Wouldn't that flash the static value?

Comment: @Landon, yes it will. But it will be momentary. So, the impact would be hard to notice.